# hodge star and intersection form

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

I'm studying $4$-dimensional manifold, we know that the hodge star operator give the poincare duality. And in dimension $4$ it gives the intersection form.

My question is, does there exist a smooth oriented four dimensional manifold $X$, for any cohomology class $\alpha\in H^2_{hodge}(X,\mathbb{R})$, we can find a metric $g_{\alpha}$ of $X$ such that $*_{g_{\alpha}}\alpha=-\alpha $ ? i.e. every cohomology class can be in the negative eigenvector space for some hogde star operator.

What's more. Does there exist a manifold and two metric $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that $\alpha$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ for $g_1$ but it is eigenvector with eigen value $-1$ for $g_2$?

I believe this is not true but I don't find a way to disprove it.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What happens if $X = \mathbb{CP}^2$ for example?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks, this example really solve this question. Seems I'm not expressed explicitly what I really want, please allow me ask here another(relative question), is there exist a manifold and two metric $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that $\alpha$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 for $g_1$ but it is eigenvector with eigen value -1 for $g_2$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the second question is more obvious since

$0<\int_M\alpha \wedge *_{g_1}\alpha=\int_M \alpha\wedge \alpha$

and

$0<\int_M\alpha\wedge *_{g_2}\alpha=-\int_M\alpha \wedge \alpha$

Which leads a contradiction.